Create relationships between entities (park, caretaker, maintenanceLog, court, equipment) for my project?
My project brief :
To run Racketminster, the town has several lush parks which contain dedicated courts for racket sports. To ensure that
they are always kept in pristine condition, the town parks are continuously looked after by specifically allocated
Racketminster caretakers who are responsible for their preservation. There are different kinds of courtsin these parks,
for people to play tennis or pickleball. Some courts are specific for tennis; others are specific for pickleball, and some
can be used for both. Each court comes with its own equipment allocated to it (typically fixed or movable items, like
nets, rackets, balls, etc.). A careful record of all the pieces of equipment assigned to each court needs to be kept.
As for parks, courts are also regularly maintained by specifically dedicated and highly trained Racketminster caretakers
to ensure they are constantly kept in full running order and that the equipment they offer is always top quality. While
not required for parks (as they are continually looked after), the maintenance of courts needs to be recorded
separately (date, time, maintenance status and maintenance log) so that a clear up-to-date maintenance record is
kept for each court, for greater transparency and accountability. Likewise, it is essential to hold accurate maintenance
records for pieces of equipment to make sure timely information is captured about their regular upkeep.
Question :
I managed to create EERD for the above project brief. But I am struggling to understand how create the relationship between the Park, Court, Caretaker, Equipment MaintenanceLog entities. The most difficult part is drawing the relationship that is related to the Court entity.
Because

When a new MaintenaceLog is created, there need to be Cartaker and the maintained entity (Park, Court, Equipment) assigned to the log.
Caretaker is also dedicated for a Court but not for other entities (Park, Equipment).

How do I make sure that when a new MaintenanceLog is created for a Court, the Caretaker who is creating the log is a dedicated Caretaker for that specific Court.
Created EERD:

This is a project that is given by my university. They have asked to use UML notation to create the diagram.
I would like to invite feedback on any errors related to the diagram or other aspects.
I really appreciate your contributions to this.
